# rm command is not execed by Permission denied

Tags: apache, symfony, capistrano, rm

in my deploy script `deploy.rb`

```
lock "3.11.0"

set :application, "myapp"
set :repo_url, "ssh://app@git.whitebear.com/home/app/myGit/myapp.git"

set :branch, 'master'
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/html/myapp"

#set :linked_files, %w{app/config/parameters.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log vendor var node_modules public/build public/dlstore config/spool}
#somehow app/cache doesn't work...

set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :debug
set :keep_releases, 3

after 'deploy:starting', 'composer:install_executable'

set :yarn_flags, "--prefer-offline --production --no-progress"
set :yarn_roles, :app
```

in `production.rb`

```
set :stage, :prod
set :symfony_env, "prod"

set :webserver_user, "app"
#set :controllers_to_clear, ["app_*.php"]
set :composer_install_flags, '--prefer-dist --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader'

server 'myapp.com', user: 'app', port: 22, roles: %w{app db web} # edit IP / Port and SSH user of your production server
SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = "php #{shared_path.join("composer.phar")}"
```

I set keep_releases 3, however when I deployed I have permission problems.

I don't know why permission is changed by Aapache though,

Is it possible forcely exec `rm` when deploying??

```
 DEBUG [cd2bf6b1]   cannot remove `/var/www/html/myApp/releases/20190212120003/var/cache/prod/pools/VQruNbwKF0/X/3/tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t'
 DEBUG [cd2bf6b1]   : Permission denied
```

Comment: I assume that directory is created by apache during runtime and your running capistrano user is not part of the apache group? The only way to force it is with sudo. You should make sure your running cap user is part of the apache group and the default umask for apache makes files readable by group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem caused by poor server configuration or deployment ran via wrong user. You u try to execute a script with user x and permissions for that file belongs to www-data and your user x is unable to remove it you will get this error. Your user has to have rights to remove that file. The user which executes the script is not the same as user that executes web request.

Comment: In my configuration, apache is run by `app` / `app` and my webserver_user is `app` as well,And all files are belonging to app/app. However somehow after accessing webserver, files under `/var/cache/prod/pools/` are owned by `root`. Is there any places I need to check??

Comment: Configure your user which executes deploy so that user have right to remove files created by apache server. Your user 'app' have to have rights to delete files created by webserver if webserver is apache then user group will be 'www-data'. You are unable to change this via configuration your server admin has to add proper rights to 'app' user.

Comment: You may have cron or some other service that is being ran by root user. Then cache files will have root as an owner.

Comment: For example project may have a supervisor task running as root or CRON. There are multiple scenarios how those files can be owned by root.

Comment: wow!!!  @vytsci you pointed out correctly. I have cron script by root. It must cause my problems.

Comment: Yes, your CRON scripts should be ran by 'app' user also, otherwise you will get permission problems.

Comment: Thank you very much you solve my long-standing problem.

Comment: @whitebear no problem :)